# Make palindrome substring finding algorithm O(n)

Tags: c#, algorithm, big-o, combinations

I recently did an online challenge and was asked to find the number of all consecutive `chars`, where it is symmetrical.

e.g. `02002` would give the following

3 x `0`, 2 x `2` (single digits are symmetrical)

1 x `00`

`020`, `200`, `002` (last 2 can be re-ordered into `020`)

`2002`

`02002` - Can be re-ordered into `20002` or `02020` (but counts as 1)

I have come up with the following solution, but it was marked as `not scaleable` (assuming because it is O(n+1C2) [n +1 *choose* r] rather than O(n).

It did say that there is an O(n) solution to this problem (I purely made an aciton method available to verify output)

```
    public int TotalCombinations(string S)
    {
        var sum = 0;

        FindCombinations(S, (s, i, arg3) => sum++);

        return sum;
    }

    public void FindCombinations(string S, Action<string, int, int> action)
    {
        var singles = new HashSet<char>();
        var comparisons = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < S.Length; i++)
        {
            singles.Clear();

            for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                var val = S[j];

                if (singles.Contains(val))
                    singles.Remove(val);
                else singles.Add(val);

                if (singles.Count <= 1)
                    action(S, j, i);

                comparisons++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{S.Length} = {comparisons}");
    }
```

And some tests I created:

```
[TestFixture]
public class DemoTest
{
    [Test]
    [TestCase("0",1)]
    [TestCase("5",1)]
    [TestCase("00",3)]
    [TestCase("002",5)]
    [TestCase("0202",7)]
    [TestCase("02002",11)]
    [TestCase("020028",13)]
    [TestCase("0200282",16)]
    public void DemoTest1_1(string input, int expected)
    {
        var test = new Solution();

        var res = test.TotalCombinations(input);

        res.Should().Be(expected);
    }

    [Test]
    public void ExampleOutput()
    {
        var res = new List<string>();

        var test = new Solution();

        Action<string, int, int> action = (s, from, to) => 
        res.Add(s.Substring(@from, to - @from + 1));

        test.FindCombinations("02002", action);

        res.Should().BeEquivalentTo("0", "0", "0", "2", "2", "00", "020", "200", "002", "2002", "02002");
        foreach (var v in res)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless they are talking about using a pre-computed lookup table I don't see how you could make this O(1), I would think the best case would be `O(n)` because you must at least read in each character once.

Comment: sorry I mean O(n)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain it was memory usage was supposed to O(1), and time was O(n)

Comment: Contains is reudandant when you call Remove. Not that it matters much.

Comment: @CSharpie thanks! never even realised remove return boolean! haha

Comment: You can look for Manacher's Algorithm, this is exactly the algorithm that helps you find out all the palindromic substrings in a string in LINEAR TIME and uses only LINEAR extra SPACE. Although the standard use of this algorithm is to find the longest palindromic substring in a string, but once you understand the algorithm, you can easily modify it to report the longest palindromic substring centered about all the characters of the array. It uses Dynamic Programming and idea is pretty much similar to Z-Algorithm.

Comment: I think such challenges are pointless. They ask you to e.g. remember the Manacher's algorithm or re invent it, which the latter I'd say is almost impossible (during the challenge) and the former (memorizing implementation of bunch algorithms) is useless. You may just know such algorithm exists (in this case I think it is useless, whenever you face such a rare strange problem you can google it).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I completely agree with you! Being asked to re-invent an algorithm is completely useless! You just need to be aware, and when you come up against a bottleneck, a bit of googling around will help you find it.

Comment: @premktiw If you post that as an answer I will accept it! I never heard of Manacher's algorithm and it looks like the correct one answer to go for. Looks like I have some learning on my hounds over next couple of days!